# Is this the shortest route served by an Airbus A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, short-haul

Is this the shortest route served by an Airbus A320? Port Louis to Saint-Denis, 231 km (144 mi). Air Mauritius flight MK248.

[image]

Comment: Looks pretty short to me, are you curious because of the course changes near the airports? Or are you asking if this is historically the shortest route that an A-320 serves?

Comment: Basically, both!

Answer (score 12):

[This site seems to indicate](http://www.routesonline.com/news/29/breaking-news/252206/fastjet-to-introduce-shortest-regular-a320-family-service-as-it-returns-to-zanzibar/) that they had the shortest route using the A-320 family of aircraft at just over 70km. The page also shows a list of flights, and it looks like one of them is listed at 58km. Based on that list, it looks like your 231km flight wouldn't even break the top 10.

[image: Short A-320 Routes]

Its difficult to search based on the length of the route and the aircraft type. As far as I can find though, 58km ACE->FUE shortest scheduled route for the A-320.

Comment: Who is "they" in your first sentence?

Comment: the article topic was about fastJet, so that is the "they", although the chart in the article disputes the claim.

Comment: I think it's not in the table because fastJet hasn't started flying the route yet.

Comment: Even if it was, it still isn't the shortest, they claim 70km, the shortest in the list is 58, so fastJet would fall in at number 4.

Comment: I think the fastJet flight will be the shortest daily service. Further down in the article it talks about how the other short flights are less than daily. I found that confusing too.

Comment: Just as side info: The canary islands are quite popular destinations for vacation for Europeans. They fly there mostly with A320 and 737. It seems the aircraft just hop to the next island before flying back.

Comment: I'm wondering, if first four aren't simply single operated flight marketed under four different carriers (i.e. code share flight). Seems possible. If yes, then placing these as four different items in list seems a bit confusing, as by single flight I understand single route. But, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. The shortest route with an A319, which is an A320 family aircraft that I am aware of is Dar es Salaam - Zanzibar (HTDA, HTZA) which if I recall is roughly 73 kilometers (probably even less from airport to airport) operated by FastJet Tanzania.

Source [here](http://www.fastjet.com/us/en/destinations)

Answer (score 1):

The shortest A320 route I know of is from Dammam to Bahrain. The flight duration is 15 minutes.

Comment: Welcome. It may help the quality of the answer if you include the airline(s), actual distance, and a reference to confirm.