# What is the shortest regularly scheduled commercial flight?

Tags: commercial-aviation, commercial-operations

Interesting to know is this flight profitable or not.
Why this route exist?
Maybe train or car will be cheaper?

Comment: Related: [What is the rationale behind very short distance flights?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23970/1696)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Westray to Papa Westray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westray_to_Papa_Westray_flight)

> Flights on this route are scheduled for one and a half minutes, and actual flying time is closer to one minute. The record for the fastest flight is 53 seconds.

By road/ferry it's 59 minutes according to Google Earth:

[image]

It's flown with a [Britten-Norman BN-2 Islander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britten-Norman_BN-2_Islander).